# Sorting the subdocuments in a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to sort a mongo collection's subdocuments, where some relate to others.  There is an 'id' field for each collection that goes up incrementally, and a parent field that can be blank but otherwise refers to another entry.

So it looks like this:

- Name: A ID:1 Parent: null
- Name: B ID:2 Parent: 3
- Name: C ID:3 Parent: null
- Name: D ID:4 Parent: 1
- Name: E ID:5 Parent: 2

And I want it like this:

- Name: A ID:1 Parent: null
- Name: D ID:4 Parent: 1
- Name: C ID:3 Parent: null
- Name: B ID:2 Parent: 3
- Name: E ID:5 Parent: 2

How do I sort it like that?  Or merge multiple searches together into one?

Comment: It's not clear how you want to sort items. But see `sort` here: http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find (or use lodash to sort, but you probably don't want that)

Comment: Sort by parent would not give me the correct order.  It would give me all with no parent, then each with parent by ID.  I need it to go parent, each child, each of their children recursively, then the next entry.

Comment: You can use sort: with parent: -1. Or use lodash orderby/sortby